# Amoraim unique to Masechtas

Tags: talmud-gemara, amoroim, rogatchover

I heard before (I think in the name of the Rogatchover) that there is one Amora in every masechta of Talmud that does not appear in any other masechta.

Is there a source for this, and is there a list somewhere of each masechta's unique Amora?

Comment: That legend of the Rogachuver has never been verified http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2007/01/which-is-more-impressive-debunking.html

Comment: @DoubleAA I would think it would be a pretty easy one to test, with computers.

Comment: Computers won't help you decide if he said it or not...

Comment: FWIW Tamid has [רבי ינאי בר נחמני]([g tamid 29a])

Comment: @DoubleAA Computers could confirm the veracity of the rumor.  I'm not so much interested in who said it. My question is pretty clear about what info I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, and I didn't downvote. But you mentioned the rumor about the Rogochuver and I commented to give you information about the rumor.

Comment: I thought it was the Yerushalmi exclusively

Comment: I heard this in the name of the Vilna Gaon...Either way. Regardless of who supposedly said it or not, did anyone ever make a list to confirm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attribution to the Rogetchover is, according to Rabbi [Bechhofer](https://www.academia.edu/3017775/The_Talmud_Yerushalmi_on_Kodashim_Or_Shmuel_HTC_Skokie_IL_pdf_file_), "an unverified legend related in the Yeshiva world."

Something very much like this was written by the **Meiri** in his introduction to Pirkei Avos (starting [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2835&st=&pgnum=42)), where he goes through each Masechta listing all of the tannaim that appear there for the first time.